# Save As Template button, if application criteria changes, should the changes also be saved on Save As Template click?

Tags: desktop-application, save, templates

Usability Issue I am running into with team:

When in the middle of an application, there is a Save as Template button that, when clicked, opens a modal to name the template, then once template is saved, returns you back to the previous application you were working on, not the one you just created.

My question is, if you change the criteria in Step 1 without hitting the Save button below on that page, and click "Save as Template", should the edited areas be saved with that template creation? Or should there be a modal telling the User they need to save first? Do you see the button being named incorrectly?

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [bakerdesign.ca](http://bakerdesign.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/saving.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Sorry - this question isn't very clear. Could you perhaps rephrase it? I don't want to add an answer if I've misunderstood the question :)

Comment: In filling out a 12 step application, to proceed to next step,the User needs to click "Save,next step".We are trying to create a "Save as Template" action because this is so long.To begin building the template they can be on any step and click "Save as Template". The question is,if, for example they are on Step1 and click "Save as Template" before clicking the "Save,next Step" button,should the content they just entered save upon the click of "Save as Template" or should a dialog come up saying they haven't saved their content first,or should it save regardless of them clicking the below save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should the edited areas be saved with that template creation?

**Absolutely!** Users are inherently lazy when it comes to filling out forms (or any data entry) no one would fill out anything they didn't want to be saved while executing any other save functionality.

When you create a template it should always be from the applications *current visual state* no matter when the last "Save" was performed. That would be the user's expectations at least.